# Derivative of a two variables function

Tags: functions, derivatives

If I have a 2 variables function $f(r,\theta)$ and I want to find the derivative of it with respect to $\theta$ so that $\frac{\partial f(r,\theta)}{\partial \theta}=kf(r,\theta)$ where $k$ is a constant, must the function be a product of $g(r)h(\theta)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is YES. Compute $\frac {\partial} {\partial \theta} \frac {f(r,\theta)} {f(1,\theta)}$ using quotient rule. You get $0$! Hence, $\frac {f(r,\theta)} {f(1,\theta)}$ is function of $r$ alone. Call it $h(r)$. You now get $f(r,\theta)=h(r)f(1,\theta)$.

Note: We can replace $f(1,\theta)$ by $f(r_0,\theta)$ in the proof. The only assumption we need is that $f(r_0,\theta)$ does not vanish anyhwere for some $r_0$.

Comment: Is this true also for a three variables function $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ with the condition $\frac{\partial f(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial \phi}=kf(r,\theta,\phi)$ with $k$ a constant, must $f(r,\theta,\phi)=g(r)h(\theta)l(\phi)$?

Comment: No. $e^{\theta}+e^{\phi}$ is a  counter-example.